# Variable Transformation using Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF)

Tags: data-transformation, standardization, aggregation

Consider two different data time-series, ***Data1*** and ***Data2***,  expressed using **inhomogeneous scales (units)**. Each of these two data series is itself a weighted-average of a bunch of **standardized** individual series.

I would like to aggregate these two data series into one unique "index", by taking the equal-weight average of the two series at each point in time.

However, before doing that, I must put these two series on a common scale. The predominant method is using standardization, i.e. by subtracting the sample mean from the raw values and dividing this difference by the sample standard deviation. However, this assumes that the variables are normally distributed. ***This assumption is clearly violated in the case of the series I am using.***

One other method suggests to do the transformation of the raw values on the basis of their empirical cumulative distribution function (CDF) involving the computation of order statistics.

I am not sure if this method is valid in my case for the following reason: 
- Let's take the first data series ***Data1***. Imagine this series only has 5 data points: (2,-1,4,10,100). The transformed values using order statistic would be: (2/5, 1/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1). When you plot the raw values against time, it seems steady for the first 4 time periods, and there is a jump at t=5. However, when you plot the transformed values against time, there is no evident jump from t=4 to t=5. Therefore, the interpretation of the transformed values is not intuitive.

[image]

[image]

Can I still use the order statistic to transform those two data series? If not, would there be any better way of aggregating them?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "I am not sure if this method is valid in my case for the following reason: each of these two data series, Data1 and Data2, is itself a weighted-average of a bunch of standardized individual series.": can you explain why you think that is a problem for using order statistics?  Transforming using the cdf just means saying that the 99% highest value of Series 1 is comparable to the 99% highest value of Series 2, the 75% highest value of Series 1 is comparable to the 75% highest value of Series 2, etc.

Comment: Well, here is the problem I currently have with the CDF method. The series I am studying are economic indicators of financial stress: when the value is high, there is stress, when is low, no stress in the economy. Imagine if my raw series has only 5 data points: (2,-1,4,10,100). The transformed values using order statistic would be: (2/5, 1/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1). When you plot the raw values against time, it seems steady for the first 4 time periods, and there is a jump at t=5. However, when you plot the transformed values against time, the jumps seems not to be proportional to the raw jumps.

Comment: The interpretation of the graph of the transformed series looses intuition, since we see no real jump between t=4, and t=5. However, on the equivalent graph of the raw values, the jump from t=4 to t=5 is pretty obvious.